# Partitioned view and performance for the table with huge records

Tags: sql, sql-server

Currently I am facing performance issues with queries and
stored procedure. Following is the scenario:

We have 3-4 tables in a database (`SQL Server 2000 SP4`) which
have huge amounts of records. One of the tables has more than 25 million
records. These tables are maintaining sales records and thousands of
records added into them daily. Whenever a stored procedure is executed it takes
15-30 minutes to complete. There are 3-4 joins on the table. Users are
complaining about it frequently. Indexes are correct. To improve the performance
we have implemented partitioned views. The solution was implemented by
referring the following [article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190019%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

We have split the sales records by year wise and performance
has improved, a query/stored procedure now takes takes 3-5 minutes to run. To improve
the performance further, we split the sales records by month wise. We are maintaining
4 years of data and now we are close to having 48 tables for sales data (After
splitting sales data by month). I was expecting this to improve the performance. But
that is not happening. The query is executing much slower than the previous one
(year wise splitting of data) which surprises me. Also after looking at the
query plan I found that it is doing an index scan on all 48 sales tables instead
of scanning only the relevant tables. E.g. When queried to store procedure for the
period `19-NOV-2012` and `20-DEC-2012`, it should consider only 2 tables `NOV-2012`
and `DEC-2012`. But it is considering all 48 tables.  So my question is:

1. Why is it considering all tables instead considering only
   relevant tables. E.g. In above example `NOV-2012` and `DEC-2012`
2. Why the year wise logic (split sales records by year) is
   performing better than month wise logic (Split sales records by month)

Following is the code for partitioned View.
For example year Other years are omitted.

```
    SELECT * FROM tbl_Sales_Jan2010
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM tbl_Sales_Feb2010
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM tbl_Sales_Mar2010
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM tbl_Sales_Apr2010
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM tbl_Sales_May2010
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM tbl_Sales_Jun2010
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM tbl_Sales_Jul2010
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM tbl_Sales_Aug2010
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM tbl_Sales_Sep2010
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM tbl_Sales_Oct2010
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM tbl_Sales_Nov2010
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM tbl_Sales_Dec2010
```

Following is the table structure.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_Sales_Jan2010](
    [SalesID] [numeric](10, 0) NOT NULL,
    [StoreNumber] [char](3) NOT NULL,
    [SomeColumn1] [varchar](15) NOT NULL,
    [Quantity] [int] NOT NULL,
    [SalePrice] [numeric](18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [SaleDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [DeptID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CatCode] [char](3) NOT NULL,
    [AuditDate] [datetime] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_tbl_Sales_Jan2010_EditDate]  DEFAULT (getdate()),
    [SomeColumn2] [varchar](15) NULL,
    [SaleMonthYear] [int] NULL CONSTRAINT [DF__tbl_Sales__SaleY__Jan2010]  DEFAULT (12010),
    [SaleDateInIntFormat] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tbl_Sales_Jan2010] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [SalesID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tbl_Sales_Jan2010]  WITH CHECK ADD CHECK  (([SaleMonthYear] = 12010))
```

Following is the query

```
SELECT     SUM(C.Quantity) as total
    FROM         Productdatabase.dbo.tbl_Product A , Productdatabase.dbo.tbl_Product_Category B, XDatabase.dbo.vw_Sales_Test C, tbl_Store D
    WHERE     A.ProductID = B.ProductID AND B.CategoryID = @CateID
    AND C.SomeColumn = A.PRoductCode
    AND D.StoreCode = C.StoreNumber
    AND D.country = @country
    AND D.status = 0
    And C.SaleMonthYear between @BeginMonthYear and @EndMonthYear               
    AND C.SalDate between @FromSaleDate and @ToSaleDate
```

Comment: Table design, partioned view details, index details and the actual query would really help

Comment: 25 million may be more than you're used to, but it's not *huge*.

Comment: I'd like to see the query plan. I cannot see a reason why partition elimination would not work here. You have swapped month and year, though, which might lead you to believe it does not work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whoever set up the partitioning did not really think of what he is doing. Besides not using partitioning (which is a SQL Server function), most likely for cost...

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_Sales_Jan2010
```

in the Union add the WHERE conditions to that, then the query analyzer can rule out the tables that are not relevant due to bad where clause right there. I.e. add:

```
(([SaleMonthYear] = 12010
```

right there.

Second, fix your other issues. Really. Point being:

> We have 3-4 tables in a database (SQL Server 2000 SP4) which have huge
>   amounts of records. One of the tables has more than 25 million
>   records.

Let me laugh. 25 Million is not tiny, not small, but "Hugh" is what? I mean, I worked with tables adding hundreds of millions of rows PER DAY and keeping the data for 2 years. 25 Million is something a mid range Server handles easily. I suggest you have either bad Hardware (and I mean bad), or some really other things going on.

Design issues like:

```
[SaleMonthYear]
```

This should not exist - it should be SaleYearMonth, so you can make a range test (between 201005 and 201008) which you can not do efficiently now, and you totally bork any index ordering if you ever use that.

This is ridiculous because this being a number you totally bork the gain here.

```
Whenever a stored procedure is executed it takes 15-30 minutes to complete
```

Let me be clear here. On acceptable mid range Hardware for a sitaution like that (i.e. proper Server, 32-64gb ram, a dozen to 24 high Speed discs) there is NO WAY this takes 15 to 30 minutes. Not the code you wrote there.

Unless you have stuff like lock congestion (bad application design) or the Server overloaded with other things (bad application design / bad Administration). I would expcet a query like that, with proper indices, to return in way below a Minute.

Anyhow, partitioning works by eliminating a lot of the checks fast - and is also / mostly a delete optimization in your case (you can just drop tables, no Need to have a delete Statement make hard index updates). THe way you implemented it, though, is not the way MS sasys it should be done, not the way logic says it should be done and shall give no result as your Partition is not integrated into teh query.

If you look at tables and query, it still must check every table.

Comment: Thanks a lot for detailed response. I have implemented your suggestions (adding where clause in view and fixing SaleMonthYear column). Performance has definitely improved. But still Query plan shows that it is scanning all sales tables. So I think there is definitely room for improvement. As you mentioned partitioning is not implemented correctly may be because of cost. Can you please provide your suggestions for partitioning and how it is going affect cost?

Comment: SQL Server Enterprise License has support for partitioning functions. Check the documentation. The licensing cost overhead is - ah - steep. In your approach the query plan will always show all tables - the question is whether they have real IO happening. LOGICALLY they are evaluated (just false, so no real IO). Run a query in management studio, check the REAL - not evaluated - query plan for the real overhead of them.

Comment: Yes. I have checked actual execution plan for the query which I mentioned earlier. Following are some values from the actual execution plan. 
For tbl_Sales_Jan2012
 Esitmated I/O Cost - 3.27397744
 Number of executions- 4
 CPU Cost -0.1980018

For tbl_Sales_Feb2012
 Esitmated I/O Cost- 5.8109117
 Number of executions - 0.3508584
 CPU Cost- 4

Comment: @parag Those are VERY low numbers. 3POINT2 io  not exactly a lot. I would assume the ones for the "real" tables are a lot higher? Like - a hundred times or more?

Comment: @parag Btw., thanks for telling me my answer was helpfull, then going straight to the other answer that is just a documentation quote and making it as correct so he gets the spoil. Well done.

Comment: Can SQL Server not handle 25M rows quickly without 32GB of RAM and 12 hard drives? How many rows can SQL Server handle with 16GB of RAM and 1 hard drive?

Answer (score 1):

From the very same MSDN article you have quoted:

> CHECK constraints are not needed for the partitioned view to return the correct results. However, if the CHECK constraints have not been defined, the query optimizer must search all the tables instead of only those that cover the search condition on the partitioning column. Without the CHECK constraints, the view operates like any other view with UNION ALL. The query optimizer cannot make any assumptions about the values stored in different tables and it cannot skip searching the tables that participate in the view definition.

In your question, you are specifying a query which has a date range - 19-Nov-2012 to 20-Dec-2012. I assume that would be the value contained in SaleDate column, but your constraint is on SaleMonthYear Column.

Are you sure that the constraint defined is correct? Could you also please post your query?

Raj

Comment: I think you intended to have that block as a quote, not as code (as code, it all went on one line, producing a massive scrollbar, and it attempted to syntax highlight it too.

Comment: Yes I indeed wanted to quote. Sorry about the mix-up. Thanks for fixing.

Comment: -1. Totally irrelevant, not explaining the point and not an answer to the problem.

Comment: TomTom - The response was posted before the OP posted the actual query. Thanks for the downvote